# How to invoke AWS lambda function from another lambda function and return without waitng for the called lambda result

Tags: aws-lambda

I am having two AWS lambda java 8 function "lambda A" and "lambda B". "lambda A" function invokes "lambda B" function and waits till it gets the result of "lambda B". But I want to invoke the "lambda B" and return the "lambda A" function immediately. Is it possible to implement and any reference links related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the AWS Lambda SDK for Java you can set the [InvocationType within the InvokeRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.html#withInvocationType-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvocationType-) object. This will just invoke your function, but won't wait for a response.

From the Javadocs:

> By default, the Invoke API assumes RequestResponse invocation type. You can optionally request asynchronous execution by specifying Event as the InvocationType.

Example:

```
AWSLambda lambdaClient = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient();
InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest();
request.withFunctionName(name)
       .withInvocationType(InvocationType.Event)
       .withPayload(payload);
InvokeResult result = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
```

Please also consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836686/replacement-for-aws-lambda-invokeasync-deprecated) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365009/how-to-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-asynchronously) question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you please also clarify me, if I write the "return" next to invoke line. Will it call successfully the lambda B function and also return executes immediately without waiting for the invoke result.

Comment: I assume you mean something like this: 
`InvokeResult result = lambdaClient.invoke(request);  return ...;` ?
This will just invoke your function, you'll get a response that it's invoked and you can return whatever you want. See also [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)